# How to get number of row of SQL statement

Tags: php, html

It's possible to get the number of row of a statement?

I try this

```php
$stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `participation` 
   WHERE id_evenement = '$id_event' 
   AND id_membre_participation ='$id_membre'");

if ($stmt2 == 0) { 
   echo 'ok'; 
} else { 
   echo 'no';
}
```

but i have this error :

```
Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\wamp64\www\projet\[...] on line 55
no
```

the statement is correct, if I try this in php my admin :

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM `participation` WHERE id_evenement = 9 AND id_membre_participation = 1
```

I have

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1    |
+----------+
```

And if I change `id_membre_participation` to 2 :

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM `participation` WHERE id_evenement = 9 AND id_membre_participation = 2
```

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     0    |
+----------+
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PDO::query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) returns a result set as a `PDOStatement` object, from which you have to get the actual data. In this case you only have one value, which you can retrieve with a call to [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php). Try this:

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `participation` 
   WHERE id_evenement = '$id_event' 
   AND id_membre_participation ='$id_membre'");
$count = $stmt2->fetchColumn(0);
if ($count == 0) { 
   echo 'ok'; 
} else { 
   echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `fetchColumn` to get number of rows

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE foo = bar"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```